# Printing a .ZPL file to generic/text printer automatically?

Tags: printing, zebra-printer

I'm trying to get this as simple as possible for our users.

Currently I go to a website, program shipping info, and it gives me a file in .ZPL format to print. This is just a text file renamed .ZPL with Zebra Programming Language in it.

When they open this file, I want it to immediately prompt for which printer it should go to.  That's it.

I've ran the below in command line to associate .ZPL to auto print in Notepad but it tries to go to the default printer.  I need a way for it to allow the user to choose which printer it needs to go to.  My only alternative is to have them open it in notepad and trust them to press File -> Print which I don't.  Any ideas?

assoc .zpl=zebrafile
ftype zebrafile=%systemroot%\system32\notepad.exe /p %1

Comment: You need to use /PT option in notepad. Look at this article: http://alinconstantin.blogspot.it/2012/08/notepadexe-command-line-arguments.html

Comment: I know about that option but that still requires you to specify the name of the printer.  I need a dialogue box to open and allow the user to choose.  Each user will have a different named printer they are attached to.

Comment: Give a shoot at this utility and let me know if solve your needs. http://www.lerup.com/printfile/

Comment: Working as a developer I've done more or less exactly what you're asking. There are two quite simple ways to go about this:

1. If you're the person behind the site have a look at a Java Applet called jPrint. It might solve it for you right in the browser.

2. Create a small application that listens to a directory on the machine, once a .zpl file is dropped there it fires up a print dialog and, by using this Little class from MS (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091) you push it straight to the Generic/text printer as raw ZPL-code to be printed.